# How to handle two process in C++ (One OpenGL app which runs on gesture by a camera)

Tags: c++, opengl

i am trying to work with this robotic arm which i made in OpenGL. My intention is to control this Arm with gestures. I get the gesture information from my camera. The only problem is the Camera also continuously looks for user info to recognize gesture and also the glutMainLoop() of OpenGL never returns anything. So either my OpenGL app runs or my camera works

So i can't figure out a way to handle these two continuous processes. I dont want to use threads for it because that will just make it complex.

Is there another way to solve this problem.

Comment: Parallel-Processing has to be developed with threads!

Comment: Oh yeah wrong tag, I am not sure whether the problem i have calls for threads. Thanks for responding.

Comment: I don't know how you are implementing the camera app, but I would use the camera app to run frame by frame, that is, return 1 frame per call. This would be slower, but it would ensure that your opengl app runs perfectly, and also no threads to worry about :)

Answer (score 0):

Poll your camera in a glut callback, e.g. `glutIdleFunc`. If the API for your camera doesn't support polling, you have to use threads. The camera thread would store the control information in some variable, which the glut main loop can then use for drawing.